# What is wrong with these auto layout constraints?

Tags: swift, autolayout

### What I aim:

I want to have a table cell, in which every cell is horizontally divided in two halves. The upper half will contain 4 labels, and the lower half will contain 4 values which correspond to these labels.

Of these 4 items in every horizontal half, each of the last 3 items will occuppy 2/7 of total width, and the remaining 1 item will occupy the remaining of the total width, which is 1/7 of total width.

### What I tried:

Putting a horizontal stack view in the content view of table cell.
    Which will contain two vertical stack views
        Where the upper vertical stack view will contain the labels and the lower vertical stack view will contain the values.

In short, I did this:

[image: constraints]

But I am getting these conflicts:

[image: conflicts]

I really don't understand why I am getting these conflicts. I feel like I have provided enough constraints for auto layout to do the layout correctly.

Could you please tell me what is wrong here?

I'm on Xcode 8 and using iPhone 7 Plus as view, if that would make any difference.

This is a simpler case, and it isn't working as well:

[image: label only constraints]

Conflicts:

[image: label only conflicts]

Answer (score 0):

As you have provided the detail nobody can get understand and help to resolve your auto-layout issues, I suggest you to clear all constraints and try re-apply all the constraints again , give proper leading and trailing with x and y position the constraints will definitely works good,

Once you will try to apply twice or thrice you ll get know the exact problem and it will be get resolved quickly.

For auto-layout more practice needed to understand it briefly.

Hope it will help to you,

Thanks.